# Disable right arrow key in the ComboBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I'd like to disable the right arrow when I'm using the `ComboBox` control in the Compact Framework 3.5.

I already tried that :

```
private void Combo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right))
  {
    TxtPass.Focus();
    return;
  }
}
```

but the `ComboBox` value change.

I looked the 2 methods described on this page : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/F8F2FE7D-A908-4AAF-BD5C-627529BB9805

But the 2 methods doesn't work for the compact framework. (the properties don't exist).

Does someone has a good idea?

regards

---

Edit

I just find the solution

```
private void Combo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right))
  {
    TxtPass.Focus();
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old school, but works very well.

[**Disclaimer:** I do not have VS2008 installed where I am now (at home), so I can not verify that the `ComboBox` item `SelectedIndex` is part of the Compact Framework. If it is not, you'd have to find some other technique to parse through your `ComboBox` items.]

```
int comboIndex; // Add 1 variable

private void Combo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (comboIndex != comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
  {
    if ((e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Right))
    {
      TxtPass.Focus();
      comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboIndex;
      return;
    }
  }
  comboIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex; // Don't forget to set this!
}
```

Comment: your answer work great but I found another good solution, I'll take the other. Thank you jp2code !